# Get Word from href using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Heyo,

so I got a `script` that turns normal `anchor href's` into `id hrefs` (for example: `/10001-Link1` to `#Link1`). Now this works fine as long as you repeat the code for every single `anchor link` you want to turn into a `id link`. But I want to make it less static. So that instead of repeating the code for every single `anchor link` the script should get the correct word out of the current `anchor href` automaticly and just replaces the word with the rest of the url and puts a `#` before it.

So here is the code that works only for the first URL:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('li a').each(function(){ 
  var oldUrl = $(this).attr("href");
  var newUrl = oldUrl.replace("/10001-Link1", "#Link1");
  $(this).attr("href", newUrl);
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="/10001-Link1">Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="/10002-Link2">Link 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="/10003-Link3">Link 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="/10004-Link4">Link 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="/10005-Link5">Link 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

Now I alredy searched for a solution for this Problem. But the only thing I found was a line of code I couldn't really understand.

```
$('a[href^="http://stackoverflow.com"]')
   .each(function()
   { 
      this.href = this.href.replace(/^http:\/\/beta\.stackoverflow\.com/, 
         'http://stackoverflow.com');
   });
```

I get the first part were every href that starts with http://stackoverflow.com is getting a `.each` function. But I don't know what all the `/`'s and `\`'s by the `.replace` part do and mean. Maybe this is not even the right solution for my problem at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regex for that.

`.replace(/\/[0-9]{5}-/, "");` replaces the regex match with an empty string. Just add a `#` in front of it and you got the desired result.

The regex works as followed:

- `\/` looks for a `/` (need to be escaped).
- `[0-9]{5}` looks for 5 numbers.
- `-` looks for (you never believe it) a `-`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('li a').each(function(){ 
  var oldUrl = $(this).attr("href");
  var newUrl = "#" + oldUrl.replace(/\/[0-9]{5}-/, "");
  $(this).attr("href", newUrl);
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="/10001-Link1">Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="/10002-Link2">Link 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="/10003-Link3">Link 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="/10004-Link4">Link 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="/10005-Link5">Link 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That worked perfektly ... the only thing im still not understanding is how these / and \ work ... how is this even called ... is there any tutorial were i can read about that?

Comment: @MarkBaijens no worries :D I didn't downvote so I won't remove it ;) but I'll add an upvote for yas:p

Comment: @Pelle2010, I edited in an explination. If you have more questions about it feel free to ask.

Comment: @MarkBaijens alright ... now i understand much more ... thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use lookbehind assertion (which should have a decent support):

```
var newUrl = oldUrl.match(/((?<=-)).*$/)[0]
```

this will retrieve anything after the `-`,
then you can use the variable to compose the new `href`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('li a').each(function(){ 
  var oldUrl = $(this).attr("href");
        var newUrl = '#' + oldUrl.match(/((?<=-)).*$/)[0]
  $(this).attr("href", newUrl);
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="/10001-Link1">Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="/10002-Link2">Link 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="/10003-Link3">Link 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="/10004-Link4">Link 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="/10005-Link5">Link 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('li a').each(function () {
        var url = this.href;
        url = url.split('-')[1];
        this.href = this.href.replace(this.href, "#" + url);
    });
});
```

Comment: You should add an explanation to help OP understand the problem/solution - code only answers aren't answers IMO :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using the [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) `/\/\d{0,5}-(.*)$/` that means: from the `/`, 5-digit digits and `-` to the end of the string..

Code:

```js
$('li a').each(function () {
  this.href = '#' + this.href.match(/\/\d{0,5}-(.*)$/).pop();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="/10001-Link1">Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="/10002-Link2">Link 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="/10003-Link3">Link 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="/10004-Link4">Link 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="/10005-Link5">Link 5</a></li>
</ul>
```